Why does FindInstance[x>0,x] give 27?
Why does FindInstance[x>0,x] give 27? I would think it would give 1… maybe 2 or some small positive decimal.

What a missed opportunity to return 42!

Because as Options[FindInstance] shows, the default RandomSeeding is 1234

Because it uses built-in random seed. You can change it as follows
  FindInstance[x > 0, x, RandomSeeding -> 1]
  (* 81 *)

  FindInstance[x > 0, x, RandomSeeding -> 555]
  (* 100 *)

To get 27 use the builtin value:
  FindInstance[x > 0, x, RandomSeeding -> 1234]
  (* 27 *)


think it would give 1

To get one do
 FindInstance[x > 0, x, RandomSeeding -> 5]
 (* 1 *)


What a missed opportunity to return 42!

 FindInstance[x > 0, x, RandomSeeding -> 35]
 (* 42 *)


It looks like it's the same as RandomInteger[{1, 101}]. On the other hand, FindInstance[x >= 0, RandomSeeding -> something] returns numbers from 0 to 101, but returns 0 about half of the time and 1..101 about half of the time.
